# Publishing a beta apk by mistake

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded to the google developer console a 90% finished app in the beta channel. I have not configured any type of test. The app form is not even the final one (the main icon, the screen shots and so on are only test images). There is not even a production APK. By mistake, i hit the publish button! Now there is a message saying something like: updating in progress.
What will happen now? 
Will my unfinished app be accessible on google play by everyone??
If so, can i unpublish it, finish it and republish again??
Thank you.

---

**Update.**
Google says that only a production APK will be visible on google play store, while a alpha/beta apk will be visible only to beta testers.

Comment: unpublish it once published!

Comment: Yes you can simply unpublish it !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the process has ended, you can unpublish the apk and delete or upload a new version without problems.

Wait for a few hours and then you can do it, don't be nervous.

Good luck

Comment: Do you know if hitting the publish button with a beta apk make the app public on the google play store and accessible to everyone? I thought that only production apk would be elegible for a public release (while beta apk would have only restricted access, with a special link or something).

Comment: Hi Marco. You're right. The beta APK is private and is not available to everyone. You can share the beta apk by invitation with your friends by gmail and they can download it by google Play. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable the beta test under 'All Applications' > 'APK' > 'Beta Testing'. There's a `Disable beta testing` button.